# What encoding does Drupal use for generating URLs

Tags: uri

I wanted to decode the 81f4c5ed/5a05/4432/a542/6205dde00d46 bits of the URL into something which can be understood, like a date etc.

The URL was generated through Drupal CMS. What kind does Drupal use to encode URL, I would like to decode these

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) You're probably going to need to provide some more information to make this answerable. What part of Drupal generates these URLs? What do they relate to exactly?

Comment: I wanted to know how drupal generates url for its pages or links. Does it have different methods to encode urls like hash, md5 etc.?

Comment: No, it doesn't have anything like that